# scanf is not very forgiving in C

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code, I wish to give an option to the user to type 'e' to exit the code and see the results, instead of 100 as used in the code presently . But code is unable to run properly with 'e' from the terminal since scanf expects an integer, matching with the declared type. If I type in any character instead of an integer, scanf would store it in the variable in some manner. is that manner fixed? if it is fixed can I use that stored value to check if to exit program or not?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int rating[11], x;

    for (int a = 0; a <= 11; a++)
        rating[a] = 0;

    while (1){
        printf("key in 100 to see the results\n");
        printf("Enter the rating on a scale from 1 to 10 ?");
        scanf("%i", &x);

        if ((x < 1 || x > 10) && x != 100)
            printf("bad entry ! \n");

        if (x == 100){
            printf("\nRatings..............No of responses\n");
            for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
                printf("%2i.......................%2i\n", y, rating[y]);
            return 0;
        }

        rating[x]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you type in an `'e'`, `scanf("%i", &var);` will fail and not store anything in `var`. If you want the option for different types of input, `fgets` a line and `sscanf` it.

Comment: Couldn't you just change 'x' to be a char instead of an integer? Or, if x is being used for other values, initialise another variable and then something like.. if(x == 'e') { // show the results }

Comment: try putting scanf in an if statement. if it receives something other than what its supposed to it'll return an error code

Comment: "scanf is not very forgiving in C" *::chokes back laughter::* Yep. Not very forgiving at all.

Comment: I see it the opposite way.  `scanf` doesn't judge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully read (or -1 on error). So, you could conceivably check to see if `scanf` returns 0, and bail in that case; it would exit the program if anything non-numeric was entered.

If you specifically want to check for `'e'`, the best bet is to `fgets` a whole line of input, check for your special cases using `strcmp`, then use `atoi` to get an integer.

Comment: Better to use `strtol` rather than `atoi` to get an integer (since it has error handling).